# Different static instantiation

Tags: c#, oop, singleton

I am having trouble in understanding difference between

```
 private static Singleton instance;
```

and

```
  private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
```

Why should I use `readonly` keword here ???

can anyone please explain in **simple words**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'readonly' is not necessary. But it's helpful. It's just telling the compiler that you never intend to reassign anything else to instance after your initial creation.

This is probably what you intend, so the more information you give the compiler, the better it can help you avoid any mistakes.

Note that readonly fields have to be assigned in the member declaration line (like you have done) or in the constructor.

See Microsoft documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: What If i change it to `volatile` will it be better than `readonly`

Comment: 'volatile' and 'readonly' are completely different concepts. It is meaningless to think of one as 'better' than the other. They are different tools for different purposes. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to make only one instance of my class

Comment: Implementing a Singleton is a different matter. A common approach is to make sure your Singleton class has a private constructor, and a static public method which just returns the same object each time (rather than making new ones). This stops anyone creating more than one class instance. But that's a whole new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask whether you need `readonly`?  Answer is no. It just makes sure that you don't change the value of the variable unintentionally anywhere in your program.

When a static field is marked as `readonly` that means that it can be assigned a value only in two places.

1. Static field initialzer.
2. Static constructor.

Also worth mentioning `readonly` plays no role in "Reflection". You can set value to field marked `readonly` at anytime using "Reflection"

Answer (score 0):

The variable is marked readonly means that it can be assigned only during `static initialization`

The common language runtime takes care of the variable initialization

Answer (score 0):

Adopt a rule: if you're not going to put some value in class field in your code, excepting constructor (no matter, is it static or instance), then declare it as `readonly`. Otherwise, declare it without `readonly` keyword.

This helps you to avoid your own logical errors.